# Who is this goggles-wearing character from the second My Hero Academia S3 intro?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The second opening of *My Hero Academia* S3 features three rapid-fire shots of a red-haired character wearing goggles and a very smug grin ([YouTube reference](https://youtu.be/WUDWBg4cFiw?t=19s)):

[image: the red-haired character wearing goggles on the intro]

These shots are placed right after the title card, implying he's going to be a significant character in the Provisional License Exam arc, but I don't recall him actually appearing at any point. I waited until the final episode came out to ask this, just in case he showed up towards the end of the season, but as far as I can tell, he still hasn't.

I check through the lists of *MHA* characters on both MyAnimeList and TV Tropes, and couldn't find him on either of them.

**Who is this guy?** And if he didn't appear, or appeared so briefly that I forgot about him, **what's the significance of his appearance in the intro?**

Comment: Not sure an answer, but based on a quick search, Japanese fans on Yahoo! Chiebukuro speculated an anime-original character or Power Loader's daily costume.

Comment: Power Loader's hair is orange, not reddish-brown, so I don't think it's him. If he's an anime-original character but hasn't appeared yet, then there might not be an answer until (and unless) he does appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This character is a anime-only character, not appearing in the manga or an anime episode as of yet.

Most likely just for something to look cool in the OP.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to get a more satisfactory answer than this.